# How to filter a DataGridView with TextBox

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I want to try to filter a `DataGridView` with a `TextBox` , but I'm receiving this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' occurred in
>   Npgsql.dll
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception

```vb
Dim strSql As String = "select * from Caixa where Recibo like '%" + textBox18.Text + "%'"
Dim con As New Conexao 
Dim cmd As New npgSqlCommand(strSql, Conexao.Conectar)   
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim da As New npgSqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable()
da.Fill(dt)
GDLoadCaixa.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257565/searching-in-datagridview-using-textbox-vb-net/48257798#48257798>

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim con As New Conexao 
Dim cmd As New npgSqlCommand(strSql, Conexao.Conectar)
```

These lines smells. You create a connection object (good), then you don't use it but you rely on a global object to establish the connection to the db inside the sqlCommand creation (bad). Don't forget that `npgSqlCommand` expects a connection object, with could be different than whatever `Conexao.Conectar` is returning.

You probably want something like

```
Dim con As New Conexao 
con.Connectar() 'Connect THIS connection  
Dim cmd As New npgSqlCommand(strSql, con) 'use THIS connection
```